# error: Failed to connect socket to '/var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock': Connection refused

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, kvm, libvirt, vfio

I added a virtual network card from a physical network card to the xml file of the virtual machine.

```
 <devices>
  <interface type='hostdev' managed='yes'>
    <driver name='vfio'/>
    <source>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x86' slot='0x0a' function='0x7'/>
    </source>
    <mac address='52:54:00:6d:90:02'/>
  </interface>
  </devices>
```

When I execute virsh define, I get error info

> error: failed to connect to the hypervisor

> error: Failed to connect socket to '/var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock': Connection refused

I tried reinstall libvirt qemu ,but no effect.

Answer (score 2):

Try these steps:

```
sudo setfacl -m user:$USER:rw /var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock
```

Exit the session and again logged in then,

```
sudo systemctl enable libvirtd
sudo systemctl start libvirtd
```